# OAuth2 client_secret column not allowed to be null

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, client, database-schema

Why is in [this `OAuth` database scheme](http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/cookbook/) from Brent Shaffer the `client_secret` column not allowed to be null (`client_secret VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL`)? Is this the common configuration for a valid OAuth database schema?

The OAuth2-Server Module can also be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php) but also [in the PDO scheme there](https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php/blob/develop/src/OAuth2/Storage/Pdo.php#L466) the `client_secret` column is set `NOT NULL`.

```sql
CREATE TABLE oauth_clients (
  client_id VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL, 
  client_secret VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL, 
  redirect_uri VARCHAR(2000) NOT NULL, 
  grant_types VARCHAR(80), 
  scope VARCHAR(100), 
  user_id VARCHAR(80), 
  CONSTRAINT clients_client_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (client_id)
);
```

It is quite common to have public clients that don't need a password. I see that people set an empty string(`''`) in such cases, but a `null` values seems much cleaner to me.

Is there some special reason to prohibit null values in this case?

Comment: Be careful: a public client is not a password client without password.
It seems that this server only supports password clients, so take care if you create a password client without password, you may have a security issue. For example, this client could be used to issue access tokens using client credentials grant type.

Comment: @FlorentMorselli I don't really understand your comment, how exactly does it become a security risk? Could you elaborate in an answer or could you share a reference where I can read more on this issue?

Comment: e.g. #1: as per RFC6749, a public client must register a redirect URI when using auth code response type. But not confidential clients. If your server knows your client as a confidential one, it will not return an error if it receives an authorization request with redirect_uri='http://my.evil-sever.com/callback'. The resource owner grants your client, but is redirected to http://my.evil-sever.com/callback. Then my evil server can issue an access token.

Comment: e.g. #2: public clients cannot use Client Credentials Grant Type -CCGT-  as they have no credentials. But if your password client has no password, then any malicious client that knows your client ID (really easy to know: it is public) can try to get an access token using the CCGT (if your client is allowed to use this grant type obviously).

Comment: To conclude: no, `client_secret=NULL` is not fine. It could potentially be fine only if your server requires that clients register at least on redirect URI (see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-3.1.2.2) and that these clients are not allowed to use CCGT

Comment: @FlorentMorselli Ah okay, thanks for the explanation. So if the client is public (`client_secret` is null) but grant type is password all is fine right?

Comment: Yes, only if it is the only grant type allowed for that client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an [answer on GitHub](https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php/issues/644#issuecomment-142615795): *"NULL is fine for `client_secret`"*.